# Confusing return statment

Tags: java, methods, return

Trying to pass `x` from method to another, then sum it before printing it in `main`.
The program works perfectly, but 8th line is confusing me. I need a brief breakdown of this code, which I obtained after following the IDE's errors warnings

```
1 package tttt;
2
3 public class Class {
4
5   public static int test() {
6
7       int x = 1;
8       return test2(x);
9
10  }
11
12  public static int test2(int a) {
13       a += 2;
14       return a;
15
16  }
17 }
```

```
package tttt;

public class fff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
        System.out.println(Class.test());
    }

}
```

Comment: how does it confuse you?

Comment: looks fine to me, `x=1` -->`a=1` -->`a=a+2` -->`a=3` -->`return a` --> `return test2(x)` --> `println(Class.test())`

Comment: x=1 ==> test2(1) ==> a=1 ==> a=3 ==> return 3 ==> return 3.

Comment: You understand what a method call looks like?

Comment: Thank you for your replies,  I am still trying to understand why test2(x); alone wont work, what is return job here ?

Comment: the 8th line can be changed in (or seen as) `int temp = test2(x); return temp;` || "following the IDE's errors warnings" caution - the IDE can only guess what you are trying to do, mostly only considering syntax, it does not always do the best or correct suggestion

Comment: BTW line 13 and 14 could be change to `return a + 2;` - no need to change `a` (not used any more in that method, and some/many developer consider changing method parameters a code smell)

Comment: @user85421 Now I see it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i left the comments in your code.
You can return links on data structures (List, Queue, Map) or literals like `Numbers`.

```
1  package tttt;
2
3  public class Class {
4
5    // The main method named 'test'
6    public static int test() {
7
8        // Declare and initialize a variable 'x' with the value 1
9        int x = 1;
10
11       // Call the method 'test2' with the argument 'x' and return its result
12       return test2(x);
13
14   }
15
16   // Another method named 'test2' with an integer parameter 'a'
17   public static int test2(int a) {
18       // Increment the parameter 'a' by 2
19       a += 2;
20
21       // Return the modified value of 'a'
22       return a;
23
24   }
25 }
```

All differences arise when you pass the value of a variable that is an array; the variable's value becomes a reference to the  original array. If you modify it in another method as an argument, you will alter the original array.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] d = Class.test();
        
        for (int i : d){
                System.out.println(i); /// 1, 2, 10
        }
    }
}

class Class {
    public static int[] test() {
        int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
        test2(x);
        return x;
    }

    public static void test2(int[] a) {
        a[2] = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` returns the result of an expression. An expression can be a variable, a literal, or a method call (or a combination of any of those).

Your code snippet shorter, but otherwise 100% identical to:

```
public static int test() {
  int x = 1;
  int result = test2(x);
  return result;
}
```

You don't even need the variable `x` and the method could be written with a single statement:

```
public static int test() {
  return test2(1);
}
```

Note that `test2` is a really bad method name, since it does not tell you anything about what the method does (and the method certainly doesn't test anything). `add2` or `addTwo` would be better.